# Validate a URL exists or not from DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a situation where I need to restrict a user to enter a Url which already exits in DB.
Here is the function that I am using to validate:

```
public bool IsContentUrlExists(string url)
{
      url = url.Trim().TrimEnd(new[]{'/'});
      return Context.Contents.Any(content => content.Url == url);
}
```

With this method I can validate for a Url say "/testurl/" that matches a url "/testurl" in DB.
But otherway it will not work when I go to compare "/testurl" string with "/testurl/" in DB.

I need to remove the trailing slash in both case but TrimEnd(new[]{'/'}) will not work on a column in EF query. So the following method will fail

```
public bool IsContentUrlExists(string url)
    {
          url = url.Trim().TrimEnd(new[]{'/'});
          return Context.Contents.Any(content => content.Url.Trim().TrimEnd(new[]{'/'}) == url);
    }
```

Can anyone help me with an alternative solution?

N.B: We don't have any standard for URL in our existing DB

Comment: Can't you just put the URL from the database into a string variable and then remove trailing slash and then compare the two strings? You are not trying to modify anything in the database are you so what is the problem?

Comment: This is not an ideal solution. I don't want to bring up the whole amount of data as a list or some sort and do manipulation on that.

Comment: Ah okay. No sorry was missing the point in comment above.  Seems you should be searching for a match that may OR may not have a trailing slash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code plus mine

```
public bool IsContentUrlExists(string url)
{
      url = url.Trim().TrimEnd(new[]{'/'});
      return Context.Contents.Any(content => content.Url == url || content.Url == url + "/");
}
```

Untested but something like the above shoudl work, shouldn't it?

Wing

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate you can try:

```
 url = url.Trim().TrimEnd(new[] { '/' });

 var lstUrls = new List<string> { url, url + "/" };
 return Context.Contents.Any(content => lstUrls.Contains(content.Url));
```

It compares a list of two strings: one ending with slash and the other without.
If there will be a match for any of these two strings in database then it means the URL exists!